# Clap sound detection

Tags: matlab

[image]I'd like to detect the number of claps in a given wav.file. Here's my first attempt. I can draw the spectogram but how can I print the number of claps in sound.
my output should give me "One clap" or "Two claps".

```
hfile = 'one.wav';
[y, Fs] = wavread(hfile);
mono1 = mean(y,2);

[S,F,T,P] = spectrogram(mono1,w,120,N,Fs);
thresh_l=1000;
thresh_h=10000000;
% take the segment of P relating to your frequencies of interest
P2 = P(F>thresh_l&F<thresh_h,:); 
%show the mean power in that band over time
m = mean(P2);
plot(T,m);
```

Comment: Do all of the sound files you have only consist of one or two claps?  Is there any background noise or does your sound file **only** consist of these clapping sounds?

Comment: Actually it would be nicer to give me the number of claps, but  mostly the wave sounds are consist of either 1 or 2 claps.

Answer (score 2):

To me it seems this is something you would do in the time domain rather than the frequency domain.

If the audio file is clean you could do something like this:

1. detect the global maximum of the audio signal
2. floor the signal to zero in a small region around this maximum to suppress that clap
3. repeat from step 1. until the next maximum is too low

---

The code would look like this:

```
hfile = 'one.wav';
[y, Fs] = wavread(hfile);

threshold = [user-defined];           %// amplitude to stop looping at
radius = [user-defined];              %// radius to floor after clap is detected
number_of_claps = 0;           

while true
    [max_value,idx] = max(y);         %// detect loudest amplitude
    if (max_value < threshold)        %// break if all claps are found
        break;
    end

    min_bound = max(1,idx-radius);
    max_bound = min(idx+radius,length(y));
    y(min_bound:max_bound) = 0;     %// ignore region around the clap
    number_of_claps = number_of_claps + 1;
end

number_of_claps
```

It might be necessary to change the flooring procedure so it ignores a larger portion to the right of the index, since the "decay" portion of the clap signal will last longer than the rising portion.

Comment: i get and error when trying to run it,                                                     in          threshold = [user-defined];           and
radius = [user-defined];

Comment: it cant recognize [user-defined].

Comment: @n.ah93 When I wrote `[user-defined]`, I meant that you are supposed to enter these values yourself. I can't tell you want good values are without looking at the signal. Try `plot(y)` and looking for what appropriate values would be. This might take some trial and error.

Comment: @n.ah93 I would try `threshold = 0.1` and `radius = 5000`. Does that work?

Comment: @n.ah93 - Actually providing a couple of sample files would help in order to prevent this back and forth messaging.  Our time is precious.

Comment: dear @eigenchris I wanted to post the error that i get from the code. i think that you have made the right one but why still not working i didnt get.

Comment: @n.ah93 The problem was the code could go beyond the bounds of the array. For example if a clap happened at index `1000`, and the radius we choose is `5000`, the script attempts to access `y(-4000:6000)`, which makes no sense because the array starts at `y(1)`.

Comment: @n.ah93 I've run my code on a number of test cases. I don't know what else to suggest, other than you linking to the `.wav` file which gives you the error so I can try it for myself.

Comment: it doesnt compile, just waiting for a along time without doing anything.

Comment: @n.ah93 It works fine for me. I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: ur giving the same values? I am using matlab2014 maybe this is the problem

Comment: The syntax between eigenchris and yourself is using standard MATLAB syntax where both platforms should be able to run it.  Your problem isn't with the versions.

Comment: Between your "answer" and eigenchris's code, you **did not** get his latest version.  I can't imagine how eigenchris is feeling, but I'm starting to get frustrated.

Comment: well if u are getting frustrated please leave us alone , but i am trying to solve my problem.. if you cant help me then go away

Comment: @n.ah93 I don't think I can help you further. I agree with rayryeng that you probably didn't try the latest version of the code so I'd suggest doing that. I hope things work out.